# Sidebar With Expanding Menus. [Diagram Provided]

Tags: javascript, css

I have spent about an hour trying to find a solution that can work, however, none of them come close to my desired goal. I am not expecting someone to spend the time creating it for me (its a lot of work), but I want to know how I can achieve it. Links or js fiddle would be amazing.

So this sidebar I am working on. It should have three states.

The first and second state show up on table onwards.
The default state is when the sidebar is loaded.
[image: Default state]

The second state is what happens when the user clicks on one of the icon images that are seen in the first image. It now expands to show the additional navigation. (Ex. Icon says Friends, and the new menu that appears has a list of like 10 people).
[image: Clicked State]

The Third state only appears on mobile. It basically eliminated the icon sidebar seen in the Default State (first image)
[image: Mobile State]

I appreciate any advice on how to solve this. I have tried so many different things and none come close to what I want.

Comment: @karlisup and _Programmer_, when one post a question on a _help with coding_ QA site, it is expected to provide a code sample to work from. The initial first image's markup is easy to accomplish (and if the icons would flow horizontal, one can ask about that too) and should be in the question, as code.

Comment: Do not "remove" your question. That is not how this site works.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```js
var titles = $('.title');
titles.each(function() {
 $(this).on('click', function() {
  $(this).next().toggleClass('active')
 })
});

$('.toggle').on('click', function() {
 $('.sidebar').toggleClass('hide');
});
```

```css
.toggle {
 position: fixed;
 z-index: 1000;
}
.sidebar {
 position: fixed;
 left: 0;
 top: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 width: 200px;
 padding-top: 20px;
 border-right: 1px solid black;
}
.group {
 margin-top: 16px;
}
.title {
 cursor: pointer;
 border-bottom: 1px dashed black;
}
.list {
 max-height: 0;
 overflow: hidden;
}
.list li {
 margin-top: 4px;
}

.active {
 max-height: 400px;
}
.hide {
 display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="toggle">Button</button>
<div class="sidebar">
 <section class="group">
  <h3 class="title">Click me first.</h3>
  <ul class="list">
   <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
  </ul>
 </section>
 <section class="group">
  <h3 class="title">Maybe click me.</h3>
  <ul class="list">
   <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
  </ul>
 </section>
 <section class="group">
  <h3 class="title">Nope - click me!</h3>
  <ul class="list">
   <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
  </ul>
 </section>
</div>
```

Comment: I created a sidebar with  an items.
What's next? Tell me more about those states.

Comment: What you have here is exactly what the second state + mobile should look like. The first state (https://i.stack.imgur.com/odZ3l.png) has a sidebar of icons, that will open up (when clicked), the menu you have created. (https://i.stack.imgur.com/jVIlE.jpg)

Comment: A guessed solution on an incomplete question, which lacks maybe the most important part, a code sample, is a really bad way to post an answer. (and on top of that have to run to the bus when you get comments doesn't make it better, quite the opposite)

Comment: @LGSon I'm trying my best.  Although what is your purposed suggestion? This newcomer was left behind with negative score and no comments how to improve his question. Do my answer really lacks a code sample, because it seems like - it's all it has. Deleted my in-appropriate comment.

Comment: @karlisup First, and sorry if I was unclear, but I meant the question didn't have code sample, which it should. SO is not a code writing service, also, questioner's should show an effort of there own, even if it is a small one, so by simply posting images is not good enough. (you can of course yourself, with the OP's accept, add a markup sample to the question, which will be perfectly fine). Second, what your answer lacks is an explanation telling what you did and why/how it works, which I weren't able to mentioned before, since there were no original code to base it on

Comment: All the above is also clearly stated in SO's guidelines.